# Configure site root URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

When I print the site root URL in a Razor view like this...

```
@Url.Content("~/")
```

... I get the wrong path, e.g.:

```
/mydomain.org/
```

How can I change/reconfigure my `Web.config` so that the path is correct? E.g.

```
/
```

The application is installed on a shared hosting in a virtual subdirectory.

Comment: I am not sure that you can get the root of the application with virtual paths in one single call. I think using UriPartial.Authority with other attributes might be a good start

Comment: I would only expect to see that if IIS is not set up properly on the host - make sure your application is configured properly with your hosting provider in whatever control panel they give you, and if so, then the problem is probably on their end.

Comment: In my control panel I do not have options, I can only create virtual directories...

Comment: Make sure you're not just creating them as virtual directories, but that you're also marking them as applications. When you're in IIS, there's a difference between a virtual directory and an application, and it's likely the same way with your control panel. Without seeing your control panel, I can't tell you exactly where to look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web>
  <urlMappings enabled="true">
    <clear />
    <add url="~/" mappedUrl="http://www.example.org" />
  </urlMappings>
<system.web>
```

I am not sure if this works. Maybe something to try though